# Meaning of xslt match expression

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I am migrating a xslt to php and I came across the following match expression:

```
string(node/text()[not(. < node/text())]) = '8'
```

The part that confuses me is the `[not(. < node/text())]` condition.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer given above by Akzy correctly assesses the **intent** of the match pattern: to find the text node that has the maximum value among all its siblings (i.e. all text nodes that are children of the same `node` element) and compare it to the string `"8"`; if both tests are satisfied, then there is a match.

However, there are three problems that will prevent the given pattern from achieving such intent:

1. A match pattern cannot contain an unescaped `<` character;
2. The expression does **not in fact** compare each text node to its
   siblings; it compares it to text nodes that are children of its
   child `node` element - which of course cannot exist, because a text
   node has no children. Therefore **any** text node will satisfy the
   provided predicate `[not(. < node/text())]` - as can be seen in an
   arbitrary example here:
   https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyygmE5

   In order to follow its presumed intention, the expression would
   need to be corrected to:

   ```
   string(node/text()[not(. &lt; ../../node/text())]) = '8'
   ```

   although the purpose of converting both sides to string remain
   unclear.
3. The result of the expression is a Boolean; such result will never match anything.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no such thing as a "match expression". There are two closely related things, XPath expressions and match patterns. This is a valid XPath expression, it is not a valid match pattern.

```
string(node/text()[not(. < node/text())]) = '8'
```

And, as others have pointed out, its value is always false.

Looks as if the person who wrote the code was as confused as you are.

Comment: *"its value is always false"* Not really. The value is true if the text node is "8".

Comment: Sorry, yes. The condition inside the not() is always false.